# Incompatible type error when bitshifting in Java

Tags: java, binary, comparator, bit-shift

I'm trying to do a bitwise AND comparator on some binary objects:

```
private int selectedButtons = 0x00;

private static final int ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED = 0x01;
private static final int SICKNESS_BUTTON_SELECTED = 0x02;
private static final int LATENESS_BUTTON_SELECTED = 0x04;
```

Here is the comparator:

```
    boolean absenceButtonEnabled = selectedButtons & ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(167, 56) error: incompatible types
required: boolean
found:    int
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider the advice of *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 32: "Use EnumSet instead of bit fields".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selectedButtons & ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED` is an integer, because `&` is the `binary or` operator.

To convert it to boolean use:

```
boolean absenceButtonEnabled = (selectedButtons & ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED) != 0;
```

Comment: Huge help. Makes sense (as do the other posts but I believe this was first!). Thank you.

Comment: Is it normal practice to check the ANDed value against 0? I usually compare it to whatever flag I was checking for.

Comment: If the bitflags are disjunct (use different bits), its safe to use `!= 0`. Here is ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED only one bit, thus the bitflags must be disjunct. If the bitflags overlapp (i.e. an enum [1, 2, 3, 4 ...]) then you must compare against the value itself.

Answer (score 2):

Compare it to zero:

```
boolean absenceButtonEnabled = selectedButtons & ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED != 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type of two `int`s is `int`. Try the following code.

```
boolean absenceButtonEnabled = (selectedButtons & ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED) == ABSENCE_BUTTON_SELECTED
```